# Keylogging for testing a qr scanner

Tags: c#, logging, keyboard

I need to write a program for logging input from the USB qr/line-scanners. I have to send this program to all offices of my work. The program should collect input information and send the files back for testing.

The problem is that the scanner inputs very quickly and some keys (characters) disappear.

For example, the scanner scans "01110" in the input field, but the keylogging recorded “010”.

Here is my code

```
...
while (true)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        int keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
        if (keyState == 1 || keyState == -32767)
        {
            //log...
        }
    }
}
...
```

I tried with the `GetKeyState` function, in this case all the keys are recorded, but the problem is that there are a lot of duplicates. For example: the scanner “presses” zero (0) key, but it duplicates many times and look like this “000000”.

How to write a keylogging that will log all pressed keys (even if the input comes from USB qr-scanner) ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you should rather use windows hooks instead...

Comment: _"For testing qr scanner"_ - don't you have a spare one to test on a non-production machine? Then you can simply have it fill a TextBox and you're done. It most probably just emulates an input device like a keyboard, anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: ^^ The reason I am suggesting this is: If I were to go around and tell people to install a _key logger_ on production equipment, IT-Crowd will whoop my buttocks faster than I can say "just for testing".

Comment: Why you need this data? I'm pretty sure that you just wana do this for geting prefix and postfix characters ... AFAIK they are adjustable on scanners ... set them to the one you need (fx in our envirement we set them to INS and TAB as that's how work best with our 3rd party  managment program)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation with hooks I will try.

About data: I only have one scanner, and this scanner doesn't work like the others. The last problem that the operators reported to me: "A usb qr-scanner opens the console in the browser" I do not understand how this happens. My scanner does not open the console. So I need to get all the input data to understand what's going on.

About security: The information from the usb qr-scanners is public. I can log it. But I can't use ready-made solutions (I mean program), it's forbidden by my company's rules.

Comment: The information from the scanners may be public. But will a _key logger_ also receive other input? Like a worker entering some password or customer credit card info?

Comment: Operators need to run the keylogger only when they need to write a report about the behavior of the usb qr-scanner (I mean when they scan something). If they run this program while entering passwords, this is their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help (in the comments). Hooks helped solve the problem. If anyone needs it, here's the solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/toub/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```